# Program that removes duplicate entries from an array does not remove certain entries

Tags: java, arrays, duplicates

I've written the following short program that prompts a user to construct an ArrayList of integers and then displays that same array with duplicates removed. The program works just fine with simple numbers, such as 1, 10, or even 100. Please note that sorting is not a concern in this program, as I only wrote it for myself. I do understand the implications of not having the program sorted, though.

Slightly bigger numbers are not properly detected as duplicates. For example, if I choose to construct an array with 2 integers, both with value of 700, the method does not remove the duplicates. Is there some other concept I don't understand, or perhaps a minor error in my code that I've overlooked?

```
import java.util.*;

public class DuplicateArray
{

    public static void main( String [] args )
    {

        // Variables 
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);


        // Prompt user and create an array 
        System.out.print("\nHow many items will your array contain: ");
        int size = scan.nextInt();
        ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>(size);


        // Construct the array 
        for( int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
        {
            System.out.print("Item #" + (i+1) + ": ");
            numbers.add( scan.nextInt() );
        }


        // Remove duplicates 
        compress( numbers );


        // Print compressed array 
        System.out.println("\nBelow is that same array with duplicates removed.");
        for( int i = 0; i <= numbers.size()-1; i++ )
        {
            System.out.print( numbers.get(i) + " " );
        }   


    }




    /*
    *  Removes duplicates from the input array
    */
    public static void compress( ArrayList<Integer> numbers )
    {

        // If the array is of size 1, then there are no duplicates to check for */
        if( numbers.size() <= 1 )
        {
            return;
        }

        // Traverse the array backwards */
        for( int i = numbers.size() - 1; i > 0; i-- )
        {           
            if( numbers.get(i) == numbers.get(i-1) )
            {
                numbers.remove(i);
            }
        }   
    }   

}
```

Comment: I would use a `LinkedHashSet` (if you need to preserve insertion order), or a regular `HashSet` (if you don't).

Comment: I haven't learned about that yet. Is there a logic error in my code?

Comment: Your approach will only work (as is) if you sort the `List`.

Comment: Ah, maybe I should have clarified -- if I enter only two items, each as 700, it still does not properly remove the duplicates. I understand what you mean about sorting it, though, if the user were to enter 700 5 700, in which case it wouldn't remove those 700s. But in my case, it's just 700 700, and the method still doesn't remove the duplicate 700s

Comment: Made an edit to clarify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use for comparing not this
`numbers.get(i) == numbers.get(i-1)` but `numbers.get(i).equals(numbers.get(i-1))` method.

The reason of a such strange behavior is internally JVM has a cache of `Integer` values from -128..127 (see `Integer#valueOf` method implementation). Thus `numbers.get(i) == numbers.get(i-1)` works for this number range only. But for numbers not in the range such comparing operation doesn't work and you have to use `equals` method.

Comment: I modified my code per your suggestion and it works as intended. Could you please also explain _why_ that fixes the problem?

Comment: @AleksandrH Just updated my answer with my explanation

Comment: Interesting! I did not know that. Just reran the program with two items, 127 127 and 128 128. It did indeed behave that way. How strange.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi No need to be so harsh. If you actually bothered to read my post, you would see that I revised it 16 hours ago (whereas you posted this 15 hours ago) to clarify that order is not important for my purposes here.

Comment: @AleksandrH apologies. Retracted. Just wanted to signal that there are corner cases not covered by the initial code.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous potential isssues with your compress function.

The main issue is that you're only comparing the number at position i with the number in position i-1.  Since you're not sorting your array in advance, you're not guaranteed that the position of the duplicate numbers will be next to one another.

Solution would be to either sort the array first then run your code. Merge or quick sort will get you nlog(n ) complexity.

Or you could run a nested for loop which checks each number against the whole list looking for duplicates. Keep in mind that this does raise the O time complexity to O(n^2).